# Object does not contain a definition for tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to the forums and programming in general! My code has a problem (I shamefully copied some from Unity's website) and I do not have the answer to it. I can't use it because it keeps saying that:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'tag' and no accessible extension method 'tag' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It sucks that I cannot solve this myself. Here is my code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    private object other;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0f) && hit.transform.gameObject != null)
            {
                if (other.tag == "Enemy")
                {
                    Destroy(gameObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try other.Tag. But I can't   see how you created other  object instance.

Comment: **private object other;** is telling the compiler that **other** refers to an object of class **object**. Class **object** does not have a method, property, or data member called **tag**. Also, you never initialize other so it will always be null.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!! You guys really helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem seems to be that when they copy someone else's code, you don't have their tag.

You need to add `Enemy` tag.

1. Click any gameObject.
2. Click **Inspector** tab.
3. Click **Tag** after click **Add Tag...**
4. Click `+` icon placed in the **Tags** section.
5. Now you need to add `Enemy` tag.

Thats all.

Comment: I think it might be because there is no class of object, and that they meant gameObject. Might want to add that to your answer, too. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @ken of course there is ;) but `object` is the mother of all instances in `c#` and probably not what OP wanted ^^

Comment: @bmoglu this would cause a runtime error .. Not a compile time error that tells you that the type you are using simply doesn't have the field/property you are trying to access ;)

Comment: @derHugo you can't see compile time error for wrong tag. Must definitely be a run time error.

Comment: Yes but OP posted the error `object' does not contain a definition for 'tag' and no accessible extension method 'tag' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` .. that's a compile time error ;) See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67384325/7111561)

Comment: @derHugo Okey I understand now :)

Answer (score 0):

`object` is a c# built-in alias and refers to [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object) the mother class of **everything** in c#!

What you probably ment is a [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) which is the mother class of all Unity built-in asset types.

---

This said there is absolutely nothing in your code ever assigning something to `other`.

I guess you rather ment

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        // No need to check if the transform exists
        // if there is a hit it HAS to have a transform and a collider
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, 100.0f))
        {
            // Check the tag of the hit object not of something else
            // CompareTag is better than using string based ==
            if (hit.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
            {
                // Not sure here ... you really want to destroy THIS object
                // I would think you would rather destroy the hit.gameObject 
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```